# Shortest query for MongoDB

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I have the following mongodb entries:

```js
{
   'someKey': 'someValue',
   'array'  : [
       {'name' :  'test1',
        'value':  'value1'
       },
       {'name' :  'test2',
        'value':  'value2'
       }
    ]
}
```

What would be the shortest query for finding 'value' for name = 'test2'?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're querying on array of elements and you want filtered elemnts just unwind and match:

```
db.CollectionName.aggregate( [ { $unwind : "$array" } ,{$match:{'array.name':'test1'}} ])
```

This will give you a result like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59df5b30646afdfce4084152"),
    "someKey" : "someValue",
    "array" : {
        "name" : "test1",
        "value" : "value1"
    }
}
```